# In a gamma regression, how can i interpret coefficients?

Tags: regression, bayesian, multiple-regression, gamma-distribution, link-function

My question is pretty simple, i have done a bayesian gamma regression with an inverse link, so:
        $\eta_i$=$\beta_0+\beta_1x_{i1}+\dots+\beta_px_{ip}$ <

using an inverse link, mu is the reciprocal of $\eta$, but now how i can interpret betas coefficients? agumenting an x by 1?...